# Wrapping article element around table

Tags: html, css

My markup looks like this:

```
<article>
  <header> 
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Foo </h1>
        <h2>Bar</h2>
        <h3>1337</h3>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
    <table>
      // etc
    </table>
</article>
```

I want the article element to have a border, margin and padding:

```
article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

The table varies in width (on different pages), and so does the viewport for each user. Which CSS do I have to use to make sure the article-element is always 'wrapped' around the table, e.g. has the same padding?

Default behaviour for article (or div) is 100% width, which is usually too big but sometimes too small.

Comment: I think this question needs a little more clarification. What is or isn't happening that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I made an image to explain: http://i39.tinypic.com/2z8b4mr.png. Legend: grey = viewport, orange = table, green = article-element.     What I want is 1 & 2, what happens is 3 & 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just float it and it will adopt the width of its children:

```
article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pXcKg/

Of course, if you have any elements underneath `article`, clear the float with `clear: both;`